# Export SQL query to excel with multiple worksheets and custom headers

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, export-to-excel

What I need to do is, a client wants to have a report in an excel doc with multiple worksheets with custom headers. I have tried SSRS 2008 Report Builder 2.0 but naming worksheets is not available with SSRS 2008 Report Builder 2.0. I have tried bcp in SQL Server Management Studio, but am not able to export it into multiple worksheets. I have put the queries into temp tables, is there a way to export those queries into the same excel doc but different worksheets with a different header for each worksheet.

Like this[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Notice how each worksheet has a different name and a different header.

Is this possible to do with SQL or is there a workaround for SSRS 2008 Report Builder 2.0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use SQL Server Integration Services 2008R2 (SSIS) to do this.  SSIS has an Excel Data Flow Destination that accepts a worksheet name as a parameter.  You could construct your SSIS package to populate the various worksheets of a spreadsheet this way.

Comment: I have never used SSIS could you walk me through it to get started?

Answer (score 1):

I know, I know... you too you faced the error:

```
Msg 15281, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT ‘OpenRowset/OpenDatasource’ of component ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’ because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’ by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’, search for ‘Ad Hoc Distributed Queries’ in SQL Server Books Online.
```

You can do it in SSMS through T-SQL, follow [this example](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-import-and-export-sql-server-data-to-an-excel-file/):

First you need to allow SSMS to bypass the error:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
```

Then you can save the result in a precise Excel Tab this way:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','Excel 12.0;
Database=C:\Users\Zivko\Desktop\SQL Data.xlsx;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]') 
SELECT * FROM dbo.DimScenario
```

The file .XLSX must already be there with the tab having the precise name `[Sheet1$]`